# Ping another IP on LAN resolves my own IP

Tags: ping, local-area-network

I have no network, computers attached to a router with DHCP enabled.

I have two computers, both access the internet just fine...

Typing into console `ipconfig` I get my IP:

`IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.238`

If I try to ping the computer next to me...

```
PS C:\Users\phill\Desktop> ping 192.168.1.117

Pinging 192.168.1.117 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.1.238: Destination host unreachable.
Reply from 192.168.1.238: Destination host unreachable.

Ping statistics for 192.168.1.117:
    Packets: Sent = 2, Received = 2, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Control-C
```

I disabled the firewall on both machines and tried pinging again, same issue.

For some reason when it looks up the IP it resolves my own.

There are no entries in hosts file.

Both machines are Windows Server 2012 R2, fully patched.

Any ideas? :(

Comment: If you're going to downvote, atleast tell me why.

Comment: Mouse over the down arrow; the popup says "*This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful*".  Downvotes without comment may be presumed to be for at least one of those reasons.

Comment: Try a switch instead of a router. And it does not resolve to your IP as mentioned below.

Comment: Have you checked your router configuration that both interfaces are in the same subnet? Have you run Wireshark on both servers when debugging the issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there's a few misconceptions here. The first is that the `reply from` text isn't written in the same context as it normally would.

The response is coming from your local IP address because the IP you're trying to ping cannot be found. For more in depth information about the error, see [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/557e2580-a2df-4938-9bc9-071427ec2942/destination-host-unreachable).

Now, the reason why you can't ping both computers could be one of many, many, reasons. My best guess at this stage is that there is a firewall (perhaps a non-standard one) on one or both of the computers that is dropping packets - this would explain why VMs can ping and your PCs can't - so try disabling firewalls on *both* computers first.

I would also connect both computers together using a single cable between their LAN ports (this is typically done with a special "crossover" cable, but most modern computers can automatically detect a direct connection and make use of a "straight" cable). This will rule out any issues related to your other network hardware (e.g. your router).

If you can ping on a direct connection and not via your router, I would suggest checking your router's advanced settings, as some do not allow ping requests on their LAN ports.

The third and final misconception is the reason for the downvotes - you haven't made the distinction that you are working in a professional environment, and ServerFault is specifically for *professional* systems administration questions - home networking questions should be directed to our sister site [SuperUser](http://superuser.com).

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to write up a proper response rather than just flicking me off. This is for work, in a professional environment. But because all of our stuff is in the cloud we don't have 'professional systems administrators'. This was just an adhoc thing I'm trying to do to make our development environment easier, and not a single person here can figure out why it's not working. Thanks for the ideas!

Comment: The route table on the router was corrupted. Did a reset and re-added all the settings and it works fine now.

Answer (score 2):

It does not actually resolve it to your own IP. It does try to ping the other host, which just happens to be unreachable. Basically, what it tries to tell you is:

> "Hey, here's 192.168.1.238. I tried to ping 192.168.1.117, but it's
>   unreachable."

Also, you do not need hosts entries for IP Addresses, that's only for names.

Comment: Yes I know that the hosts entries are only for names, but the first people I asked about this issue suggested looking at the hosts file, so I mentioned it so I didn't get stupid responses. 

I know that the machine is unreachable, that's what I'm trying to fix. No one can give me an answer on why two machines next to each other on the same router cannot talk to each other. Yet if I run a virtual machine on both machines, they can talk to the perfectly fine.